# Is there any registration authorities in Hyperledger Fabric framework?

Tags: linux, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

A Registration Authority (RA) is an authority in a network that verifies user requests for a digital certificate and tells the Certificate Authority (CA) to issue it.

R3 Corda has separated Registration Authority (RA) and Certificate Authority (CA). Is this configuration applied in Hyperledger Fabric framework?

Answer (score 1):

For registration purpose, so far the best option is using **[Hyperledger Fabric CA (Certificate Authority)](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/)**.

For registering an new identity, we can use **[Fabric CA Client](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html#registering-a-new-identity)**.

We can also use openssl.

Answer (score 1):

The Hyperledger Fabric CA is a Certificate Authority (CA) for Hyperledger Fabric.

It provides the following functionality:

- Registration of identities, or connects to LDAP as the user registry.
- Issuance of Enrollment Certificates (ECerts).
- Certificate renewal and revocation.

And it is not mandatory to use Fabric Certificate Authority, depends on the requirements/project we can use third party CA in Hyperledger Fabric Network.

Here is one of the link which explains the functionality of CA in details from IBM Garage.

https://medium.com/ibm-garage/using-3rd-party-root-cas-in-hyperledger-fabric-3cafa91d1260